# mywebsite.com shows index of / after installing Magento

Tags: apache, magento, apache2, httpd.conf, indexof

I am running Virtual server by:

- VirtualBox v5.2.12
- Ubuntu v18.04
- Apache v2.4.29
- php 7.1.17
- Magento v2.2.4

Everything goes fine till I install magento! Magento works find without any problem in the server but the problem here is when I entered mywebsite.com **it shows my files and indexing and I want to show my index.html instead**:

```
Index of /
Name    Last modified   Size    Description
index.html  2018-05-28 03:47    180      
info.php    2018-06-04 12:39    20   
magento2/   2018-05-01 23:21    -    
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at mywebsite.com Port 65533
```

I tried a lot of answer but without any success.

Here is /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And Here is /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf

```
Listen 65533
    <VirtualHost mywebsite.com:65533>

    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com

    ServerAdmin info@mywebsite.info
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory />

        Options FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride None

    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com/html/>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews

        AllowOverride All

        Require all granted

     </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `Options -Indexes`. In addition, you can specify which files to search to be shown `DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php`.

Comment: In which part I should use the "Options -Indexes" ?

Comment: instead of `Options Indexes`

Comment: Sorry for bothering .. but I have different file and all file has indexes part .. which file should i put this on: apache2.conf or mywebsite.com.conf ? Thanks a lot for cooperating and helping :)

Comment: You can safely try any of them. Don't forget to restart apache when you change conf files.

Comment: I tried to put it in  /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf but its gives me error when i restart the apache & I tried to arrange the DirectoryIndex and put my html in the beganning like index.html index.htm index.php but still index of / is there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue .. been trying for a week!

The solution is:
Step 1- Inside this file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf" this should be the first directory strait after the virtualhsost info:

```
<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

And it will effect the whole file.. ok so far so good.

Step 2- I added a new directory specially for magento which is

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com/html/magento2>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Step 3- `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` in order to restart the apache with status or just use any method to restart.

** The point here is you need to avoid directory Inheritance / one setting for all in order to work with each directory separately.

Hope someone get benefit from this post.

Thank you Andra for the little help.

Regards,
QLF